# Build-Depends dependency for python2.6 cannot be satisfied because package libffi4-dev has no candidate version

Tags: python

Trying to install dependencies of python using sudo apt-get build-dep python2.6
Getting following error
Build-Depends dependency for python2.6 cannot be satisfied because package libffi4-dev has no candidate version

**UPDATE:-**
All the dependencies are successfully installed except _ssl. I tried to install openssl but even after that _ssl dependency is not removed

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this http://christophermahan.com/hacking/2009/python2.6-on-debian-stable.html

I went through this about 3 years ago. I had fun with dependencies too.

I searched for "apt-get install libffi4-dev" and didn't get far.

See http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=513289 where there is a "apt-get install libffi5-dev"